# Android NullPointerException Error at Runtime

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing a simple camera app which is based on the android developers tutorial but my I'm having some issues getting it running.

Here is my LogCat printout.

[image]

Now I have traced the NullPointerException to be at line 30 in CameraPreview as you have probably figured out to so the code for CameraPreview is below. I can code in Java and know that a NullPointer is when something is there which hasn't been created yet but as far as I can tell it has been.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private static final String TAG = "Preview";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    //Install callback to get notifications from the app
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); //deprecated but required for Android Version 3.0 and under
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //Surface been created now need to tell app where to draw PREVIEW
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera preview error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

}
```

Line 30 is the code snippet here - `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);`

From what I can tell is that there is an instance of mCamera in the 'global' variable `private Camera mCamera`.

Anyone got any ideas? Sorry its a long question formatted as best I could.

Thanks,
Dan

P.S. I know there are other methods required in this class this is merely the 'problem snippet'.

Comment: post logcat errors.not an image

Comment: Waht about the place where you are calling that class??

Comment: @Robert which class do you mean Camera? because that's imported from android.hardware.Camera....

Comment: I believe you mCamera instance is null, check if it initializes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
```

Looks like `camera` is getting passed on to `CameraPreview` as null.

---

Make sure you have these in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Also, what's your `getCameraInstance()` method?

Comment: @DanielD Post the method where you pass camera to CameraPreview and I'll have a look.

Comment: the only place camera and CameraPreview are is in my constructor?

Comment: @DanielD It's where you pass the variables to the CameraPreview, it has to be somewhere. (eg. `CameraPreview cp = new CameraPreview(context, camera)`.

Comment: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_demo); //get an instance of Camera mCamera = getCameraInstance(); // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity. mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera); FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview); preview.addView(mPreview);` 

This is in CameraDemo.java is this what you mean?

Comment: @DanielD Yes, that's it. I'll have a look at it now.

Comment: In answer for some commenst above I asked where you are calling your class CameraPreview in constructor of that class you are using an object called camera (Instance of class Camera) hwre probablly will be null. In code provided above you are using getCameraInstance() method. Is that mthod responsible fo initialize object called mCamera ?

Comment: @DanielD Make sure you have the permissions/features added in the Manifest as listed in my updated answer. Also, the `NullPointerException` is occurring in the `getCameraInstance()` method. Could you post that method too please?

Comment: `public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }` that's `getCameraInstance`

Comment: does `Camera.open()` throws an exception?

Comment: @oliholz I've coded it to throw an exception but there's nothing within the curly brackets so its just `catch(Exception e) { }`

Comment: try `catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }` to check

Comment: @DanielD Seems like it's throwing an excpetion at `c = Camera.open();`. Try adding `Log.e("CameraDemo", "Camera.open() exception", e);` or `e.printStackTrace()` into the catch and post what the exception says from the log.

Comment: @DanielD I don't know, why this Answer is accepted. It gives the same Answer like me, but later than me.

Comment: @oilholz Perhaps the pemissions fixed it? I'll +1 your answer anyway since the first part was the same as mine and you posted it seconds before I did.

Comment: @BoA I'm confused I entered the code into the catch but where do I see the results? My logcat printout looks the same as before.

Comment: @DanielD Have you scrolled up to make sure it's not hidden amongst the NullPointerException?

Comment: @BoA there is one line that is of type TRACE `08-01 12:24:52.845: E/Trace(908): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
` is that it?

Comment: @DanielD That shouldn't be a problem. I get that too, and my app has nothing to do with cameras.

Comment: @BoA what about `08-01 12:34:27.475: W/dalvikvm(952): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
`

Comment: @DanielD That's just saying that an uncaught exception occurred (which is the `NullPointerException` you posted in the question)

Comment: @BoA yeah thats what I thought so nothing hasn't changed since I implemented that code. So confused! :(

Comment: @BoA Would it be worth trying this on my actual android phone? Maybe there's something wrong with my AVD.

Comment: @DanielD Have you got the permissions and features enabled in your Manifest as listed in my answer?

Comment: @DanielD I don't see any harm in trying it on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `CameraPreview` created?

Looks like `new CameraPreview(context, null)`.

You have to be sure that `CameraPreview` get not a `null`-Camera.

Comment: surely CameraPreview is created in my constructor?

Comment: Post your line, what is the 2nd Argument for `CameraPreview`?

Comment: `getCameraInstance()` brings `null`. post this method.

Comment: does `Camera.open()` throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Camera android.hardware.Camera.open()` to initialize the camera when you start your activity.

Comment: where would that go in my code, the onCreate method in the main application class? i.e. CameraDemo?

Comment: where you instantiate the CameraPreview, pass the camera using that function.

Answer (score -1):

mCamera = camera.

at this line your 'camera' object could be null.... so check it first...
like

if(camera==null){

Log.e("Camera","my camera is null...");

}

Try this.... at this way you can find the exact where the nullPointer occurs...